# Is date - TRUNC(date) ever larger than 1?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am reverse-engineering legacy code written by another company. It includes the following statement

```
UPDATE table
SET deliverydate = trunc(deliverydate)
WHERE deliverydate - TRUNC(deliverydate) > 1
```

Is this dead code? Is there any way this statement will ever match a row? Maybe some absurdly uncommon condition related to daylight saving time?

The statement is executed on an Oracle Server (version unknown).

Comment: Yes, `where` condition never satisfied.

Comment: I wonder if the original coder meant `WHERE deliverydate - TRUNC(deliverydate) > 0`, i.e. truncate any dates that have a time component?  Of course no way of knowing now!

Comment: Just guessing - maybe the code originally had it comparing deliverydate with another column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

deliverydate - TRUNC(deliverydate) is always less than one, so the update does nothing. There is no exception to that.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!